# Why does script stop working and need to be reloaded?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that I use to open Firefox that contains customized shortcuts and that closes when I close the browser. Lately when I first open it and try to use a shortcut, it does not work until I reload the script, even though the script is still running. I haven't changed anything in the script in a while. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Thanks,
Ellen

```
Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe


SetTitleMatchMode, 2

runwait C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe, , max

IfWinExist ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
    Return
ExitApp

Return


#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent


   Return

#ifWinActive Mozilla Firefox


^!b::send, ^+b

^b::send, ^d  ; bookmark page]

^n::send, ^t   ; open new tab

!c::send, ^w    ; close current tab

^d::send, ^!t  ; duplicate tab

^u::send, ^+t  ; undo close tab

!d::send, ^j  ; open downloads

^e::
MouseClick, left,  33, 44
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  33, 230
Sleep, 100

return

^r::      ; recent pages
MouseClick, left,  79, 76

return

!a::   ; click on address bar
MouseClick, left,  368,  73

return

^q::   ; roboform
MouseClick, left,  864,  722

return

^BS::send, +{Backspace}  ; forward

Up::send, ^{+}    ;zoom in

Down::send, ^{-}    ;zoom in

::abc::about:config

#ifWinActive
```

Comment: I like your abc hotstring! You realize that by using RunWait, the script will be waiting UNTIL you CLOSED FireFox..... In other words the script will be active (as an icon), but it will not be doing anything... Change runWait into run and then add a line with winwait...

Comment: Hi Robert,

I changed RunWait to Run, but I'm not sure what you're suggesting for WinWait. I added WinWait, Mozilla Firefox, then tried WinWait, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass, but that didn't work and it also kept the script from closing when I closed Firefox. I got the RunWait from another script you helped me with, where it seemed to serve the purpose of keeping the script from closing out immediately. And the thing is, the script in its orignal form does work as I want, without reloading, most of the time, but not always.

Comment: I have to retract my earlier statement. I see what you are doing and this is a very clever way! You might want to add 500 ms of sleep before you test with IfWinExists And once the origination FireFox window is closed, while another FF window is still open, the script will stay on forever. I saw a lot of unnecessary returns and blank lines in your code, but all in all, I can't find something that is wrong. But since you have created FF specific HotKeys/strings, why not keep the script running all the time?

Comment: I am very confused by all these `return` statements. Almost all of them are redundant and dead code. Also, your script **does not** close when your browser gets closed. It only checks **once after starting Firefox**, if there's a Firefox window open and exits, if there isn't. I would start by refactoring your code: Move the neutral directives to the beginning of your script; remove each `return`, if the corresponding hotkey is a one liner; And what is that `#ifWinActive` doing at the end?

Comment: OK, guys, I removed the extra returns! Thanks! Won't do that again. Let me clarify: this problem has occurred only sometimes, only on the first time after rebooting. So it is tedious to test, because I have to keep rebooting, but so far it seems to have fixed it. I have 10 scripts like this, all with the same code at the beginning, that run fine. Those don't have extra returns. MCL, the script absolutely does close when I close the program; the tray icon goes away. The #IfWinActive is there because I'm simply copying others' scripts, and it seems to work. Are you saying it's redundant?

Comment: I spoke too soon. Tried it one more time, and it's not working. How could it be so inconsistent?

Comment: @decibelle Sorry, I was mistaken. What exactly doesn't work? Please elaborate on your problem. Also, since you've refactored your code, please update it here, too.

Comment: OK. This script opens Firefox, runs while Firefox is open so I can use customized hotkeys in Firefox, and closes when I close Firefox. Lately it has not been doing this consistently; instead, it will open Firefox, and it will remain open, as demonstrated by the appearance of the tray icon, but somehow not work. This only happens the first time I run it after rebooting. If I reload the script or close Firefox (which closes the script) the next time everything will be fine. I have nine other scripts, using the same basic code, for other programs, none of which have this problem.

Comment: Sounds strange to me. Your script works for me, so the problem has to be something specific to your machine. That's why you'll need to figure it out on your own. I assume, that "doesn't work" means "no hotkey or hotstring does what it's supposed to". That's a good start. By double clicking your script's tray icon, you can see which lines are executed. Look, if your AHK registers your key presses. While debugging, I recommend removing the `RunWait`, just to make sure the waiting doesn't block another thread.

Comment: I've looked at those lines, and when it's running right, the last lines are something like 033: Return (170.50)
006: STILL WAITING (3231.13): RunWait,C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe,,max  and when it's running incorrectly, the STILL WAITING is missing. I don't know what to make of that. Another interesting thing is that if I run a similar script for another program before running the Firefox one, I don't have the problem I have described. It runs fine without the RunWait, but the point of this script is to have that working. And it works in my other scripts, so why not here?

Comment: If you finally figured this out, you might consider answering your own question.

Comment: I would if I had, but no such luck.

Comment: Use `WinWaitActive` ;)

Comment: Thanks - where would I put that, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To me the problem with your script seems to be that the `runwait` makes the script stop the the current thread that is running firefox.

That thread then waits for firefox to close giving you the "STILL WAITING"... then when it closes the next line is `IfWinExist ahk_class MozillaWindowClass` and it will not exist making the script skip to `Exitapp`

> While RunWait is in a waiting state, new threads can be launched via hotkey, custom menu item, or timer.

When using `RunWait` some programs will appear to return immediately even though they are still running, these programs spawn another process. With the way your script is setup it may stop RunWait from going into this waiting state once in a while.

And this will make you unable to launch new threads as autohotkey is not multi threaded...

---

So I say use something like `WinWaitClose` as that will also let you launch new threads

> While WinWaitClose is in a waiting state, new threads can be launched via hotkey, custom menu item, or timer.

Something like this:

```
Run, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe, , max
WinWait, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
WinWaitClose  ; Wait for the exact window found by WinWait to be closed.
Exitapp
```

Hope it helps